# In Apache Artemis ActiveMQ, Would it be possible for to configure a diverts destination to be a source to another address?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Would it be possible for the address that the messages that have been diverted to act as a source for another address? If this is possible, Would the new destination address can be have a different routing type than the source, In other words, My new source address is a multicast and the new destination is an anycast and If I understand this right, diverts between address with different routing types isn't possible from what I read here.

> Diverts can apply a particular routing-type to the message, strip the existing routing type, or simply pass the existing routing-type through. This is useful in situations where the message may have its routing-type set but you want to divert it to an address using a different routing-type. It's important to keep in mind that a message with the anycast routing-type will not actually be routed to queues using multicast and vice-versa

The setup I'm trying to configure is something like this below

```
<addresses>
      <address name="source.A">
        <multicast>
          <queue name="source.A"/>
        </multicast>
      </address>
      <address name="source.B">
        <multicast>
          <queue name="source.B"/>
        </multicast>
      </address>
      <address name="destination.AB">
        <multicast>
          <queue name="destination.AB"/>
        </multicast>
      </address>
      <address name="destination.C">
        <anycast>
          <queue name="destination.C"/>
        </anycast>
      </address>
</addresses>

<diverts>
      <divert name="divert-A">
          <routing-name>divert-A</routing-name>
          <address>source.A</address>
          <forwarding-address>destination.AB</forwarding-address>
          <exclusive>true</exclusive>
        </divert>
        <divert name="divert-B">
          <routing-name>divert-B</routing-name>
          <address>source-B</address>
          <forwarding-address>destination.AB</forwarding-address>
          <exclusive>true</exclusive>
        </divert>

        <divert name="divert-AB">
          <routing-name>divert-AB</routing-name>
          <address>destination.AB</address>
          <forwarding-address>destination.C</forwarding-address>
          <exclusive>false</exclusive>
        </divert>

</diverts>
```

Comment: So what you really want to do is send a message with `MULTICAST` routing-type to `source.A` and then divert it to the `destination.AB` which only supports `ANYCAST` and the same for `source.B`?

Comment: `source.A` and `source.B` both recieve messages with `MULTICAST` routing-type. Even `destination.AB` supports ony `MULTICAST` routing-type. Now I want to introduce `destination.C` that would support `ANYCAST` routing -type only and sources messages from `destination.AB`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be no problem to *chain* diverts together using the `forwarding-address` of one for the `address` (i.e. "source") of another.

Regarding the routing-type issue I think you misunderstood the divert documentation. The statement which says, "It's important to keep in mind that a message with the anycast routing-type will not actually be routed to queues using multicast and vice-versa," is simply describing the reason why the divert exposes the `routing-type` configuration element. Diverts between addresses of different routing types is certainly possible. As the documentation you cited explains, using the `routing-type` configuration element diverts can do one of the following:

- apply a particular routing-type to the message
- strip the existing routing type
- pass the existing routing-type through

Valid values for `routing-type` are `ANYCAST`, `MULTICAST`, `STRIP`, & `PASS`. The default is `STRIP`. As the doc states, the `routing-type` "is useful in situations where the message may have its routing-type set but you want to divert it to an address using a different routing-type."

Since the default divert `routing-type` is `STRIP` any message that flows through the divert will have its routing type removed which means it will be routed to *all* the queues bound to the configured `forwarding-address` whether they are `anycast` or `multicast` queues.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its the last sentence in the quoted text which actually confused me, 
**It's important to keep in mind that a message with the anycast routing-type will not actually be routed to queues using multicast and vice-versa**.
So, Does my config look OK for what I intend to do?

Comment: The statement you quoted is true and is the reason why the `routing-type` can be configured on the the `divert` in the first place. It describes *why* you might need to configure the `routing-type`. Your config looks fine as far as I can tell. Have you tested it?

Comment: BTW, I updated my answer to clarify. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the update, Its more clearer now. Regarding testing the proposed routing setup, Yes I did and I'm not receiving messages on Destination.C via divert.AB that I configured at the tad end. I have not specified the routing -type on any of my diverts, which means that artemis should default it to STRIP? Any ideas why this might not work?

Comment: I've also added the <routing-type>STRIP</routing-type> explicitly on the divert from destination.AB to destination.C and see no difference. I'm not receiving messages on the anycast address

Comment: I just set up a quick test in the Artemis test-suite to mirror what you're trying to do and everything worked fine. Also, the "divert" example that ships with the broker forwards messages between addresses supporting different routing types and it's working fine as well. You'd need to work up a reproducible test-case for me to investigate further.

Comment: I reviewed the configuration again and this time it seems to work. I'm not sure why it didn't work earlier though. I'm trying to use a filter in my divert to catch specific notifications. From the limited documentation about filters, I cannot see how to format the filter expression works, Any pointers you could give?

Comment: Add a new question about your filter issues and I'll take a look.